# How to force to open resource from CI route instead of File System

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-routing

I am Developing a web Application with Codeigniter in this I am having  url after routing

https://example.com/microsite/user1 for https://example.com/controller/method/para1

`$route['microsite/:any'] ="controller/method/$1";`

and I also want to create a directory with name microsite in root and user1 as subdirectory

but after creating the directory I am being served with resource in the user1 subdirectory

https://example.com/microsite/user1  that is https://example.com/controller/method/para1

How can I access to the resource available at CI using routing instead of default directory . I can't change either the Routing URL or the directory name.

Comment: do you use `mkdir()`? where's your code?

Comment: Please post your folder structure fore reference.

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda No, I am using CI the url locate to right resource but when I am creating directory and sub-directory with the name similar to the url structure the the url locate to the resource at the created directory not as specified in the routing. I want to over ride the default

Comment: You can used same Routing used. but in controller side action inside add fore example $this->load->view('user/microsite/index', $data)